# How to take command line parameters from a file

Tags: windows, command-line, command-line-arguments

I've got a file each line of which contains an URL. All those urls one by one need to be passed as a command line parameter to a certain program. How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default `cmd.exe` command shell has a `FOR /F` built-in that can read from files:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in (url-list.txt) do certain-program.exe "%a"
```

See `FOR /?` for more details. Note: It's `%a` for usage in interactive console windows, and `%%a` for batch scripts.

Answer (score 1):

If one is using [JP Software's TCC/LE](http://jpsoft.com/tccledes.htm), one can of course use the CMD syntax.  But TCC/LE has a slightly simpler syntax of its own as an alternative:

```
for %a in (@url-list.txt) do certain-program "%a"
```

TCC/LE doesn't make a fuss about whether one uses `%a` or `%%a` after the `for`, and accepts both forms universally.

### Further reading

- JP Software. [*FOR*](http://jpsoft.com/help/for.htm).  Take Command / TCC Help.